# How change data in dataframe into multiple row in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter

I have a question.
So I have data with this kind of column and row:

```
OrderNum   WPNo ProdNum
       1   23       4
       1   56       2
       1   35       4
       2   54       7
```

So I want to change it into:

```
OrderNum WPNo
1        23
1        23
1        23
1        23
1        56
1        56
```

I have difficulties changing it because this is my first-time code in python.
Can you help me? I use jupyter notebook with python 3.0

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
df = df[['OrderNum','WPNo']].loc[df.index.repeat(df.ProdNum)].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: If this solved your problem, then do accept it as answer. Or if any other answer solved your problem then do accept their answer as the answer for this problem

Comment: Ahh.. yes.. thank you.. This is my first time asking in stack overflow.. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Is your data in csv format ? In that case, just try to remove the word between the first and 3rd item. If it is a list, or another data-structure you can try the standar methods to work on it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have already loaded your table in a pandas dataframe

```
import pandas
df = pandas.DataFrame({"OrderNum": [1,1,1,2],"WPNo": [23,56,35,54],"ProdNum": [4,2,4,7]})
df_new = df.reindex(df.index.repeat(df.ProdNum))
df_new = df_new.drop("ProdNum",1).reset_index(drop=True)
df_new
```

Comment: Repeat the observation based on the your column of Preference and then drop the unwanted column

Comment: Thank you so much.. It is working... have a nice day~~